# JS/JQuery Image transition effects - blinds?

Tags: jquery, flash, image, jquery-plugins, transition

I'd like a transition effect between 2 or more images. I know that simple transitions can be easily done in JQuery, especially with the [Cycle](http://malsup.com/jquery/cycle/) plugin, but I want something more complex.  [Like this](http://www.pixel2life.com/publish/tutorials/631/how_to_create_a_diagonal_opening_blinds_transition_effect_for_images_in_flash_2/), although it's a poor example. A 'blinds' style effect where you can see one image through the other as it changes. I hope I'm clear.

I really would like to avoid using Flash if possible.

---

I've used `animate` a few times already. What I want is a way to implement the style of transition I linked to, either ready-made or with a little help. My problem is that the image is essentially split up, not just moved. Maybe there's a way to use masks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're fine with the vertical blinds option, there's a very slick jQuery plugin out now that will do the effect you're looking for: [http://nivo.dev7studios.com](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Diagonal blinds are going to be nearly impossible with javascript alone.  I can think of a few ways to do it with image files, but it would be a holy hack and the animation is unlikely to be smooth.  There are probably ways to do it with canvas, but that would be a headache as well because you have to use a canvas->vml to make it work with IE.

If you are okay with horizontal/vertical blinds, just append a bunch of divs and animate the width/height.

Comment: +1 diagonal blinds are going to be almost impossible to get right, especially and have them be cross-browser compatible.  However vertical or horizontal blinds should be just fine.  Make sure to offset the new image an appropriate amount in each of the child divs, and just shrink/grow them.